# Outputting text that auto updates to screen and file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to take a script I have that updates my sytstem for me, and have it output it's text to a file, and the screen. This is fairly simple using `tee`, except my update manager, `pacman`, outputs the same kind of text like `wget`. Here's some sample output.

```
 core                                                                              107.0 KiB   392K/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
 extra                                                                            1531.8 KiB   719K/s 00:02 [################################################################] 100%
 community                                                                           2.1 MiB   818K/s 00:03 [################################################################] 100%
```

When I try to redirect that kind of output to a file using `tee`, this is the output I get to my screen and file.

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
downloading core.db...
downloading extra.db...
downloading community.db...
```

I understand this is because `pacman` uses a buffer to output to the screen, but I'm still hoping there's a way I can output the status to the screen and the file, and not just the "downloading xyz...".

Thank you in advance for any help.

Edit:

I have no current updates, but here's some sample output that's very similar of me installing the Opera browser. The lines with the percentages and the pound signs are buffers that update with the progress of the download.

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Packages (1): opera-12.16.1860-2

Total Download Size:    10.49 MiB
Total Installed Size:   45.03 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages ...
 opera-12.16.1860-2-x86_64                                                          13.4 MiB  1151K/s 00:12 [################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                              [################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                            [################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                 [################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                           [################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                         [################################################################] 100%
(1/1) installing opera                                                                                      [################################################################] 100%
Optional dependencies for opera
    gstreamer0.10-base-plugins: HTML5 Video support
    gstreamer0.10-good: HTML5 Video support
```

This is what the above output looks like when redirected through `tee`.

```
warning: opera-12.16.1860-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Packages (1): opera-12.16.1860-2

Total Installed Size:   45.03 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
checking keyring...
checking package integrity...
loading package files...
checking for file conflicts...
checking available disk space...
reinstalling opera...
```

As you can see, the download progess isn't shown. Just three periods.

Comment: By status you mean the download progress?

Comment: @rendon Yes, the finished result. In other words, I'd like the exact output on the screen, to also be in the file as well.

Comment: Please extend your example output.

Comment: @rendon I extended my sample output, and what it looks like when redirected through `tee` to help show the problem that I'm facing.

Comment: I think that `pacman` uses **nCurses** to display dynamic content in the screen, the text shown using **nCurses** isn't normal text (i.e. STDIN, STDOUT or STDERR) and therefore `tee` save to the file only normal text received from `pacman`.

Comment: @rendon I see, that makes sense. So what would you recommend I do to save it's output with the download progress? It's a vexing problem...

Comment: I can't find a way to solve your problem, an interesting problem though.

Comment: @josh - See my updated answer - I think `script` should be able to do what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note sure if I fully understand the question, but I think possibly your script outputs to both stdout and stderr and you want both to be captured to file as well displayed on the terminal.  In which case, you could do this by redirecting stderr of your script to stderr, before piping the whole thing to `tee`:

```
./myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

---

So I think you also want *all* the output with respect to progress bars, etc.  You can use the `script` command to get this:

```
script -e -q -c "./myscript.sh" output.log
```

This works for me with `wget`:

Terminal output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ script -e -q -c "wget http://stackoverflow.com" output.log
--2014-02-21 20:01:31--  http://stackoverflow.com/
Resolving stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)... 198.252.206.140
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|198.252.206.140|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 214108 (209K) [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.5'

100%[======================================>] 214,108     7.59K/s   in 38s     

Last-modified header invalid -- time-stamp ignored.
2014-02-21 20:02:13 (5.55 KB/s) - `index.html.5' saved [214108/214108]

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Contents of output.log:

```
Script started on Fri 21 Feb 2014 08:01:31 PM PST
--2014-02-21 20:01:31--  http://stackoverflow.com/
Resolving stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)... 198.252.206.140
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|198.252.206.140|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 214108 (209K) [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.5'


 0% [                                       ] 0           --.-K/s              
 1% [                                       ] 3,367       3.66K/s              
 2% [>                                      ] 5,863       5.09K/s              
 3% [>                                      ] 7,111       3.54K/s              
 5% [>                                      ] 10,855      3.73K/s              

### Output omitted - I have a slow connection right now ###

97% [=====================================> ] 209,806     7.84K/s  eta 1s      
99% [=====================================> ] 212,302     7.44K/s  eta 1s      
100%[======================================>] 214,108     7.59K/s   in 38s     

Last-modified header invalid -- time-stamp ignored.
2014-02-21 20:02:13 (5.55 KB/s) - `index.html.5' saved [214108/214108]
```

Comment: That still doesn't work, the buffers don't get printed. Just the text that's static. I.E the download progress, it just get's ignored.

Comment: I extended my problem a little bit, hopefully it helps. I may be explaining this poorly, but I'm not really sure how best to explain it.

Comment: +1 The redirection `2>&1` causes `wget` to print the progress bar as a normal STDOUT text.

Comment: His code works perfectly if you subtract `tee` from the equation. With `tee`, it chops off the download progress and replaces it with the three periods. The problem seems to be within `tee` not handling dynamic content as you put it.